# Dynamic PickerView with multiple components: Index out of range

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I have a PickerView with 3 components based on this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824401/3-component-dynamic-multi-uipickerview-swift). The two picker to the right change their content based on the previous selection to the left. 
Unfortunately the app crashes when I change a parent picker to another one with less rows than the previews one:  Fatal Error: Index out of range.

[image: GIF of the current state and crash]

I tried to return the child picker to their first position after selecting another parent picker, but it didn't worked out. (Please see under `didSelectRow`

Do you have another idea?

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if component == 0 {
        return countries.count
    } else if component == 1 {
        let selectedCountry = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        return countries[selectedCountry].cities.count
    } else {
        let selectedCountry = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let selectedCity = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
        return countries[selectedCountry].cities[selectedCity].posts.count
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if component == 0 {
        return countries[row].name
    } else if component == 1{
        let selectedCountry = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        return countries[selectedCountry].cities[row].name
    } else {
        let selectedCountry = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let selectedCity = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
        return countries[selectedCountry].cities[selectedCity].posts[row]
    }
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    if component == 0 {
        pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
        pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 2, animated: true)
    } else if component == 1 {
        pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 2, animated: true)
    }
}
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: On what line does the crash occur? What index does it have when it says it's out of range?

Comment: @shim here is a screenshot of the message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY5V0.png. It happens under `numberOfRowsInComponent`. I think need to update the position of the selected row, before the new picker list is build. But I don't know how to do it correctly.

Comment: When you call `reloadAllComponents()` in your `didSelectRow` you haven't updated the selected rows yet.

Comment: Thank you @shim ! I changed the order under `didSelectRow`. Now I call `reloadAllComponents()` last. It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `reloadAllComponents()` in your `didSelectRow` you haven't updated the selected rows yet so it's crashing.

Change the order around and it should be fine.

[Reset the value of the 1st component of UIPickerView when component 0 is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55893829/reset-the-value-of-the-1st-component-of-uipickerview-when-component-0-is-changed) might be of interest here as well.

Note `pickerView.reloadAllComponents()` isn't strictly necessary, as pointed out in the post above. You could just reload the ones that need to change.

A suggestion as well: Your code would be easier to read/maintain if you used say an enum to organize your components so instead of `if component == 0` you could have `if componentType == .country` (or better yet, a `switch`), for example.

Comment: Thanks again, I will check that out.